# Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following in simple trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace TRIGGER PR_POZ_ZAM_CENA_TRG AFTER UPDATE ON PR_POZYCJA_ZAMOWIENIA
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
BEGIN
     UPDATE PR_POZYCJA_ZAMOWIENIA 
     SET PR_POZYCJA_ZAMOWIENIA.cena_za_sztuke = 1.1*PR_PRODUKT.cena 
     WHERE PR_PRODUKT.id_produktu=:new.id_produktu;
END PR_POZYCJA_ZAMOWIENIA;
```

heres my code, i have no idea why its wrong, I think I miss : somewhere or the query is bad, but idk how to fix it, tried using : and changing PR_POZYCJA_ZAMOWIENIA.cena_za_sztuke to new.cena_za_sztuke but it didnt work

Comment: Too much coffie, sorry. Now the error changed to "Error(4,12): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PR_PRODUKT"."ID_PRODUKTU": invalid identifier" While pr_produkt.id_produktu DO exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `BEGIN` twice, and you only `END` once. The final `END` needs to  atch the name of the trigger, not the table. (Giving the name is optional, but useful.)

You are also updating the same trigger the update is against; which will cause the trigger to fire again; which will cause a further update; which will fire the trigger again...

You can assign a column value in the row being updated, in this case with a `select ... into`:

```
create or replace TRIGGER PR_POZ_ZAM_CENA_TRG
AFTER UPDATE ON PR_POZYCJA_ZAMOWIENIA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT 1.1*PR_PRODUKT.cena
  IMTO :new.cena_za_sztuke
  FROM PR_PRODUKT 
  WHERE PR_PRODUKT.id_produktu=:new.id_produktu;
END PR_POZ_ZAM_CENA_TRG:
/
```

If that calculation is constant, it might be simpler to calculate it when querying the table, or via a view, rather than storing and maintaining that derived value.

Comment: it was supposted to be after insert, copied wrong trying-many-random-things version, anyway thanks it works that way u wrote it!